# EXTJS 5.1 Scrollable charts legend

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, legend

I have a very simple fiddle that describes my problem https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ij3.

But to sum up: I have 4 series in a bar chart. They all have a long name, so the legend is very big but the chart's width is not big enough to render the entire legend, so the last item is partially visible.
What I would like to know is if there is a way to :

- Display a horizontal scrollbar in the legend so the user can scroll to see every items

Or

- Make the items to stack on a new line when there isn't enough space

The same code is here:

```
Ext.define('CustomChart', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.CartesianChart',

    width: 390,
    height: 400,

    legend: {
        docked: 'bottom'
    },

    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        fields: ['month', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4' ],
        data: [
            { month: 'Jan', data1: 20, data2: 37, data3: 35, data4: 4 },
            { month: 'Feb', data1: 20, data2: 37, data3: 36, data4: 4 },
            { month: 'Mar', data1: 19, data2: 36, data3: 37, data4: 4 }
        ]
    }),

    axes: [{
        type: 'numeric',
        position: 'left',
        grid: true,
        fields: ['data1']
    }, {
        type: 'category',
        position: 'bottom',
        grid: true,
        fields: ['month']
    }],

    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        axis: 'left',
        title: [ 'a long name 1', 'a long name 2', 'a long name 3', 'a long name 4' ],
        xField: 'month',
        yField: [ 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4' ],
        stacked: true
    }]
});


var chart = Ext.create('CustomChart', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});


Ext.create('Ext.form.Label', {
    html: '<br/><br/>As you can see, the last item in the legend ("a long name 4"), is not visible due to the chart width.<br/>' +
    'Is it possible to:<br/><br/>' +
    '1 - Display a horizontal scrollbar in the legend so the user can scroll to see every items.<br/>'+
    '   OR<br/>'+
    '2 - Make the items to stack on a new line when there isn\'t enough space.<br/>',
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Thanks a lot in advance  !

Comment: Where's the problem? I can scroll the legend running your Fiddle without change, at least in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Hi Saki, to scroll on chrome I have to use the mouse wheel that is not very intuitive. I would like to know if I can show the scroll bar. Thanks for the reply :) !!

Comment: I don't think you can force the scrollbar to show from JavaScript. It's a browser or OS setting. (But I can be wrong.)

Comment: Ok I see ! As the legend at bottom is contained in a hbox layout, i guessed it was possible to force the scrollbar to render ^^" :

Comment: Maybe you could show an artificial scrollbar-like markup and make it work like the native one, but it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Hi JkSuf, have you solved the issue? I am also facing same problem. Will you please guide me to add horizontal scroll ...

Comment: Hi Amit, unfortunately I don't have the solution yet. But I'm still planning to implement this behavior as I really need it. I will keep monitoring this thread when I'll have my solution (but I will work on this only next week :s).  See you :) !

Answer (score 0):

i've just been looking at this problem in my application and by setting AutoScroll to true and setting the height of the legend, the scrollbar is visible.

Hope this helps